# Which translation of the Vedas is the best?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, yajur-veda, atharva-veda, translation

Which translation of the Vedas is the best? Also, what are the errors in the translation of Vedas by Dr.Tulsiram?

Comment: Do you want best translation of Veda?

Comment: Yes, I want the best translation of the Vedas and I also want to know the mistakes in the Vedic translation that Dr. Tulsiram did

Comment: @muhamadsofyanSanusi There is no best translation of the Vedas.

Comment: What about Dr. Tulsiram?

Comment: Which translation is the best --- is opinion based ... one will say this is best another will say that is best. @muhamadsofyanSanusi

Comment: Is there any mistake in the translation of the Vedas by dr.tulsiram?

Comment: @muhamadsofyanSanusi not sure as I have not read his translations of Vedas .. but even to find out all possible errors in his translations is a huge task. Not possible to be included in one answer alone.

Comment: Please check the translation of the rig weda 1.84.15 done by Dr. Tulsiram is it true or not?

Comment: Does that mean the translation is wrong?